# How to signal end of infinite scroll in AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, infinite-scroll

I have a site which I built an infinite scroll for and as you scroll it loads the next X results, but I was wondering if theres a standard or better / prefered way of signaling you have come to the end and not to do any more requests.

At the moment it justs 404s when requesting data thats after the "end" of the data. If AJAX call receives an error/the 404 in response then it will remember not to make a call anymore.

But to me it feels a bit raw and was wondering whats the usual (if any) way of dealing with this is.

Comment: Depends on what the URL you're loading represents. If you're loading a non-existing entry, then 404 is fine; but if you're calling an api it should respond with "I exist but there are no results".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your "get results" API call looks something like this:

```
$.get('/results', { start: n }, function() ...); // for ex, /results?start=0
```

And returns something like:

```
[{ name: 'Result 1' }, { name: 'Result 2' }, ... ]
```

Where `n` is the number of results already loaded, then it doesn't really make sense semantically to return a 404 error, which means the requested *resource* (which is `/results`) does not exist.  This is not true; `/results` **does** exist, but the request parameters result in no data.

It is more appropriate to return a 200 with an empty array,

```
[]
```

...or respond with HTTP 204 No Content, which means that the request was successful, but there is nothing to return.  This does save a few bytes since the server needn't send `Content-Type` or `Content-Length` headers and a response body.

(I'd use the 204.)

Either way, your client-side script knows that a 204 or an array of length 0 means that there's no more data, and can stop making requests.

Comment: Well the data returned at the momment is the full html of the new entries. So when the new data is received all that happens is that it gets appended into the div on the screen. Thats it. I thought about doing JSON, with 2 keys. A key for status such as "OK" or "NO MORE" and then a key for data which would just be the HTML but it seems its a bit messy putting HTML into JSON? So like I said at the moment on the server side, if the request does not produce any matching results it will just send back a 404. The javascript is set to when it receives a 404 it knows not to make anymore requests

Comment: In your case, you're probably better off just responding with a 204 when there is no more content.

Comment: It seems like 204 would count as a "success" to jQuerys AJAX. Thats why I was using a 404 because I just have it set to "on fail indicate end of result" as 404 counts as a fail. But it seems like you are able to detect that its a 204 so ill use that then. Thanks for the heads up about the 204!

Answer (score 1):

How are you handling paging? Often it is recommended to include a "next page" link in your AJAX response. If you do so it avoids having to do math on the client, and provides an easy communication mechanism, just don't include the link if it would not be valid.

Comment: Really? I wouldn't want you to put presentation in the data format.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Paging isn't just presentation, it is core to the data retrieval process. If you are requesting a paged resource (whether you requested it be paged or not), returning information pertinent to paging is logical. Similar to linked data, I could inline it or give you an identifier, both are valid.

Comment: Paging is just done by a page variable. On load it is set to "1" and every AJAX request increases it. Its always 30 results that get returned so its just "get results from X * 30" for every request, until it 404s (symbolising no more data)

Comment: @Guvante: Yes, I agree, but that doesn't mean you need to be transferring links in the AJAX response.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It doesn't have to be a link, a page number would work too. Also useful if you want to provide more than just back and forward one page.

Answer (score 1):

If you Ajax is returning HTML or text, then just return an empty response to signify that there is no more data.

If the Ajax is returning JSON, then you can just add "status" property to the object representation.

Either way you should probably respond with HTTP 200, not 404.

Comment: Its just pure HTML that gets returned which is then interested straight into the bottom of the div on the page. So your saying I should just swap the 404 for a 204 and thats all I need to be more "standardised"? The reason I use 404 is because to AJAX its a "failed" call. So I just have it "On fail set a variable which makes AJAX never make another call"